# How can list sorting/grouping be made intuitive?

Tags: tables, lists, grouped-list

My user is shown a list of devices as a table, say:

```
Name, OS
"Amazon Fire Phone", "Android 4.2.2"
"Nexus 7", "Android 4.3 1"
"asus_015d41d46d53f411", "Android 4.3"
"HTC_HT14NT214173", "Android 2.3.5"
"iPhone 3GS1", "iOS 6.1.3"
"Nexus 4", "Android 4.2.2"
"iPad Mini", "iOS 6.1.3"
```

When they click on a column header, it toggles sorting of that column between ascending and descending. This is intuitive because it's a common UI pattern.

I'd like to introduce grouping as well. Instead of the flat table, there would an alternative "tree" view. If they were to group by the OS column, a rough layout would be:

```
- Android
-- Android 4
--- "asus_015d41d46d53f411", "Android 4.3"
-- Android 2
--- "HTC_HT14NT214173", "Android 2.3.5"
```

How can I preserve the existing UI, and also present them with the third option of grouping by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does this reasonably well by right clicking on a column header and selecting group-by.  This doesn't work so well on the Web especially with touch interfaces -  though touch and hold is becoming more common. A tree icon by each column heading would work but would be a bit fiddly especially on small screens. A mobile style menu icon (small square with horizontal lines) could potentially be added to each column heading incorporating sorting and grouping. By combining them on one button you declutter a bit.

A common pattern emerging in the last few years is a filters panel to the left.  This works well and could incorporate grouping.

Alternatively I would have a tree icon at the top left of the table. Clicking it would display a drop down of columns to group by.